# Bringing wife, children, and mother to Germany

Tags: germany, eu-citizens, family, eu-spouses

I need some help.

I am a British national and live and work in Germany. I have four children, 9/7/5/1 years old who are British citizens by descent and have British passports.

My wife and my mother (58 y/o) are both non-EEA citizens and they, along with my children, live in Afghanistan.

Since they are all my dependents, can I bring them to live with me in Germany? How would I begin to do this?

Comment: Your children can enter with their British passports, of course. Your wife will be eligible for freedom of movement under directive 2004/38/EC; she will need a visa, but it will be free of charge and cannot be refused except under certain limited criteria. Your mother will be eligible for the same rights as your wife *only if she is dependent on you or is a "member of your household."* If she is not, it will be considerably more difficult for you to bring her to Germany.

Comment: Thanks from your lovely advice my mother is depenetly depend on me any idea how much should be my income before i apply. Best regards

Comment: If you have a job, your income does not matter.